# How can I exclude a certain column from showing and how to show columns by field_name?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have this code which shows my columns in a table. The output is:

```
'''('ID', 'int(11)', 'NO', 'PRI', None, 'auto_increment')
('Hardware', 'varchar(255)', 'YES', '', None, '')
('IP', 'varchar(255)', 'YES', '', None, '')'''
```

How can I only show the field_names such as: ID, Hardware and IP? Like:

```
'''ID
HARDWARE
IP'''
```

Second question:

How can I exclude the ID from showing? I basically just want Hardware and IP to show for later user inputs.

CODE:

```
mycursor.execute(f"SHOW columns FROM {atbl}")
for x in mycursor:
    print(x)
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: i added my code @P.Salmon

Comment: I am baffled by this - why bother interrogating the db when you know the column names you want anyway?

Comment: @P.Salmon well my first question is, how can I possibly show the columns name and not the full description of it? for example varchar(255), YES, None etc.. And second question: how can I exclude the ID column? What do you mean by db? The query says "show columns from table_name" (I just used my variable)

Comment: im sorry about my lack of knowledge. I'm new to python and coding overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a list of tuples is returned so just do some python on the output.

```
    with connection.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute(f"SHOW columns FROM {atbl}")
        cols = [r[0] for r in cur.fetchall()]
```

Something like that should work.

Comment: That worked! My first question is answered so thank you for that. The remaining question is how I can exclude the ID from showing. Thank you :D

Comment: `cols = [r[0] for r in cur.fetchall() if r[0].lower() != 'id']`